# Noun that means "something that contrasts favorably with the rest"?

Tags: word-choice

For example, when you want to emphasize the contrast of a laid-back person living in a hectic city.
I figure we can say something like "His laid-back personality is a [word] against/to the bustle of the city." but I have yet to find the right word for it

I also want the word to have a positive meaning, so it doesn't simply contrast with the rest but does so favorably.

Update: I thought of a word that is very close to this: A breath of fresh air. So it would help if the words you suggest also have a similar connotation.

Answer (score 3):

You can say his laid back personality is in stark contrast/at odds with the bustle of the city..

Answer (score 2):

You may use *[clash](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clash)*: (from TFD)

> - To create a contrasting  visual impression when placed together: colors that clash.

- His laid-back personality clashes with the the bustle of he city.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with **antithetic**.
"His laid-back personality is *antithetic* to the bustle of the city."

**antithetic**: *(adj)* directly opposed or contrasted; opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word *dissonance* or *dissonate*

> dissonance: a tension or clash resulting from the combination of two disharmonious or unsuitable elements

For example:

> His laid-back personality dissonates with the bustle of the city.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "incongruous", you don't need "a" or "against". According to some of the less traditional dictionaries, in spoken AmE, *incongruous* has evolved into a more neutral (than negative) description.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> "His laid-back personality is **[at odds](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/odds)** with the bustle of the city."

---

> **at odds**
>
> 1 In conflict or at variance:
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *His behavior is **at odds** with the interests of the company*
>
> *But conflict resolution in recent decades is **at odds** with the principled approach.*
>
> *She had felt different and increasingly **at odds** with her family, in particular her mother Fanny.*
>
> *That guidance is clearly different from and **at odds** with the 1972 decision letter.*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)